# How to initialize static class member with nontrivial constructor?

Tags: c++, windows, class, visual-c++

It is trivial in C#, but in C++ (native, Win32, Visual C++) I don't see solution. So, I have class MyClass1 with non-trivial constructor, and in MyClass2 I want to have static member of type MyClass1:

MyClass1.h:

```
class MyClass1 
{
   public MyClass1(type1 arg1, type2 arg2);
}
```

MyClass2.h:

```
class MyClass2
{
public:
   static MyClass1 Field1;
}
```

And MyClass2.cpp:

```
MyClass1 MyClass2::Field1(arg1, arg2);
```

I expect that such code will initialize MyClass2::Field and call MyClass1 constructor during this initialization. However, it looks like compiler allocates memory for Class1 only, and never calls constructor, like if I do this:

```
MyClass1 MyClass2::Field1 = *(MyClass1 *)malloc(sizeof(MyClass1));
```

Is there any "official" way in C++ to initialize static class member with nontrivial constructor?

Comment: `MyClass1 MyClass2::Field1(arg1, arg2);` will call the appropriate constructor. Show an [sscce](http://sscce.org) of your problem where it doesn't.

Comment: Beware the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html).

Comment: Yes, you right, @Fred Larson, it looks like initialization is made, but too late.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be encountering the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). Static variables of class or namespace scope are initialized before `main()` is executed, but the order of initialization is dependent on link-time factors.

To solve the problem, use the [Construct on First Use Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html), which takes advantage of the fact that function-scope statics are initialized at the time the function is first called.

Answer (score 2):

I would not expect this kind of exception that Vitaliy is getting. [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html) requires two objects where initialization of one object invokes a *method* on another object.

Here we have a static initializer in MyClass2 that invokes a *constructor* (not a method) of another class (MyClass1). Of course, we don't need to initialize object before invoking constructor.

In summary, I don't know why Vitaliy is getting this exception. I would be interested to know the answer, but it seems that it is *not* due to Static Initializer Order Fiasco.